# React: How to make registrable dynamic nav menu items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

it seems like a dumb question but I didn't find any answer on SO or Google...

I want to make a simple admin panel menu which could expose a method to dynamically add a menu item like so:

```js
function SomeRandomComponent() {

    const targetRoute = `my/route`

    sideMenu.addMenuItem('Link label', targetRoute)

    return <Route path={targetRoute}>
        <div>
            My page
        </div>
    </Route>
}
```

I didn't manage to find a good way to expose the `setState` method to other component. And I don't see another solution.

Have you got any clues on how to achieve that please?

Comment: One good way is to have a centralized state like Redux or a Store, where you would have a list of the nav items, instead of storing them in the local state of the NavMenu. Then any component could dispatch a "addNewNavigationItem" event that would change the store state, hence updating the Navigation

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many ways to do that but the most elegant is using [`ContextAPI`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) Hook in your app. Then, menu items could be dynamically iterated from the state.

If the app has implemented [*Redux*](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) it's worth to do it there. But don't overkill by implementing *Redux* exclusively for that thing.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Could you elaborate on how to achieve this please (using context or reducer) ? I don't use redux BTW...